# About a Dirichlet problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given this Dirichlet problem:

$$\begin{cases} \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}= -(\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)) \\ u(0,y)=\cos(y),\;\; u(\pi,y)=-\cos(y),\;\;u(x,0)=\cos(x),\;\;u\left(x,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0, \end{cases}$$
can we apply Fourier's theory or eigenfunctions of Laplacian to express the exact solution?

(I think the answer is no, but I'm not sure why).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the answer is yes, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Any other useful comment, akkk?

Comment: What happens when you try to use those methods?

Comment: I asked my question politely.akkkk answer was not. I came here searching ideas and opinions about my problem. Not to start a discussion.

Christopher, the question is if they can be used, or if there's any problem doing so. I think it involves the boundary conditions.

Comment: How about showing some work??